# How can I retrieve a CompositionEffect given a FrameworkElement?

Tags: uwp, windows-composition-api, xaml-composition

I'm experimenting with a chained effect and set it on an Image control (*TestImage*) as such:

```
    private void TestImage_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        /*
            (input) Backdrop -> GaussianBlur -> |
                                 ColorSource -> | Blend -> Saturation (output)
         */

        var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this.TestImage).Compositor;

        var blurEffect = new GaussianBlurEffect()
        {
            Name = "Blur",
            BlurAmount = 10f,
            BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Hard,
            Optimization = EffectOptimization.Balanced,
            Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("source"),
        };

        var colorEffect = new ColorSourceEffect
        {
            Name = "Tint",
        };

        var blendEffect = new BlendEffect
        {
            Background = blurEffect,
            Foreground = colorEffect,
            Mode = BlendEffectMode.Overlay,
        };

        var saturationEffect = new SaturationEffect
        {
            Name = "Saturation",
            Source = blendEffect,
            Saturation = 1.5f,
        };

        var factory = compositor.CreateEffectFactory(saturationEffect, new[]
        {
            "Blur.BlurAmount",
            "Tint.Color",
            "Saturation.Saturation",
        });

        var brush = factory.CreateBrush();
        brush.SetSourceParameter("source", compositor.CreateBackdropBrush());

        // Animatable properties
        brush.Properties.InsertScalar("Blur.BlurAmount", 10f);
        brush.Properties.InsertColor("Tint.Color", Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 0, 0));
        brush.Properties.InsertScalar("Saturation.Saturation", 1.5f);

        var sprite = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        sprite.Brush = brush;
        sprite.Size = new Vector2((float)this.TestImage.ActualWidth, (float)this.TestImage.ActualHeight);
        ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(this.TestImage, sprite);
    }
```

My goal is to then retrieve that effect at a later time so I can read some of the values on that effect. How can I get the effect using only the TestImage control and the Composition layer?

Comment: I'm confuse why you want to get the effect value? Do you want to edit the value and re-render ?

Comment: I'm building an animation library, so I have a feature that I need to get the effect and set new values to re-apply.

Comment: Currently, UWP does not contains such api that could retrieve the effect object then re-apply, I suggest your post your feature in UserVoice. After you have submitted this feature in Uservoice, I hope you can share this case link in here, in this way community members who have the same requirement can vote on this feature to let Microsoft raise the priority for it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I resorted to using an AttachedProperty to get around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using an attached property since this feature is not natively supported:

```
internal static SpriteVisual GetSprite(DependencyObject obj) => (SpriteVisual)obj.GetValue(SpriteProperty);

internal static void SetSprite(DependencyObject obj, SpriteVisual value) => obj.SetValue(SpriteProperty, value);

/// <summary>
/// Composition Sprite attached to a FrameworkElement.
/// </summary>
internal static readonly DependencyProperty SpriteProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Sprite",
        typeof(SpriteVisual),
        typeof(MyAnimations),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
```